# python string manipulation

Tags: python, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python string manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846818/python-string-manipulation)

Hi,

I have a string `s = AX(p>q)&E(qUr)`

I want to remove all characters between brackets and store in a new string like this:

```
new_string = AX&E
```

i tried doing this:

```
p = re.compile('\(\(*?.*?\)\)', re.DOTALL)

new_string = p.sub('', s)
```

but its still showing the same string. Is there any problem with the syntaX?

Jay

EDIT

Hello,

It doesn't seem to work for strings containing nested brackets, like this one:   AX(p>q)&E((-p)Ur)

Is there an easier way to do so, rather than iterating each element in the string? Thanks