# python string manipulation

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string `s` with nested brackets: `s = "AX(p>q)&E((-p)Ur)"`

I want to remove all characters between all pairs of brackets and store in a new string like this: `new_string = AX&E`

i tried doing this:

```
p = re.compile("\(.*?\)", re.DOTALL)
new_string = p.sub("", s)
```

It gives output: `AX&EUr)`

Is there any way to correct this, rather than iterating each element in the string?

Comment: why did you start another similar one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846576/python-string-manipulation/5846590#5846590

Comment: @ghostdog74 Prob. because the OP posted a non-nesting example there, and only realized through the answers that he needs to cover nesting as well.

Comment: yea. sorry about that :). I tried editing the previous post, seeing as i got no replies, i thought i'd make a new post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another simple option is removing the innermost parentheses at every stage, until there are no more parentheses:

```
p = re.compile("\([^()]*\)")
count = 1
while count:
    s, count = p.subn("", s)
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/WicDK

Comment: You don't need to do a search, use re.subn() which returns both the new string and a count of substitutions made ... repeat until count is zero.

Comment: @John - Thanks! I was able to write something like http://ideone.com/0zEAO - `count = 1;
while count != 0:
    s, count = p.subn("", s)` - does that seem simple enough? Can/Should I short it down to a one-liner?

Comment: @Kobi: Just do `while count:` instead of `while count != 0:`.

Comment: @Kobi: It can be shortened a little further by hoisting the `.subn` out of the loop.

Comment: @John - Got it with `while count:` - http://ideone.com/WicDK , thanks! But how can `subn` be out of the loop? I tried it in the condition, but didn't get far...

Comment: @Kobi: Do `xsubn = re.compile(yadda_yadda).subn` then in the loop do `s, count = xsubn('', s)`

Answer (score 5):

You can just use string manipulation without regular expression

```
>>> s = "AX(p>q)&E(qUr)"
>>> [ i.split("(")[0] for i in s.split(")") ]
['AX', '&E', '']
```

I leave it to you to join the strings up.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "AX(p>q)&E(qUr)"
>>> re.compile("""\([^\)]*\)""").sub('', s)
'AX&E'
```

Comment: that works. But can you please explain the ezpression re.compile("""\([^\)]*\)""").sub('', s)

Comment: That regex matches an opening parenthesis, any number of characters that aren’t parentheses, and then a close parenthesis.

Comment: YEs. But that doesn't work for strings with nested brackets. Like this: AX(p>q)&E((-p)Ur)

Comment: @Jay If you have arbitrary depth nesting, you probably should reconsider using regexes and go with something like @ghostdog74 suggested, but regarding nesting.

Comment: This doesn't work, you just changed the input string.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it should be:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "AX(p>q)&E(qUr)"
>>> p = re.compile("\(.*?\)", re.DOTALL)
>>> new_string = p.sub("", s)
>>> new_string
'AX&E'
```

Answer (score 2):

Nested brackets (or tags, ...) are something that are not possible to handle in a general way using regex. See http://www.amazon.de/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=gateway&qid=1304230523&sr=8-1-spell for details why. You would need a real parser.

It's possible to construct a regex which can handle two levels of nesting, but they are already ugly, three levels will already be quite long. And you don't want to think about four levels. ;-)

Comment: This is true for Python's regex engine; however, other implementations like .NET or recent Perl/PHP versions do support recursive regexes.

Comment: Can you please provide a pointer to some documentation and/or code sample? Would be very interesting to me!

Comment: Try something like this: `\((?:[\w\s]++|(?R))*\)` - http://regexr.com?2tln2 . I'm sure you can find the data if you look for it though.

Comment: Next, the claim that every extra level is extra ugly isn't very correct either. Using the recursive pattern as a base, 0 levels (base): `\([\w\s]*+\)`. 1 Level: `\((?:[\w\s]++|\([\w\s]*+\))*\)`, 2 Levels: `\((?:[\w\s]++|\((?:[\w\s]++|\([\w\s]*+\))*\))*\)` . Every extra level is a *little* more complex (linearly), and you can easily build that string automatically for any given level of nesting. (you basically paste the pattern instead of `(?R)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) to parse the string:

```
from pyparsing import nestedExpr
import sys

s = "AX(p>q)&E((-p)Ur)"
expr = nestedExpr('(', ')')
result = expr.parseString('(' + s + ')').asList()[0]
s = ''.join(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), result))
print(s)
```

Most code is from: [How can a recursive regexp be implemented in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656859/how-can-be-implemented-recursive-regexp-in-python)

Comment: The last two lines are from somewone who doesn't know much Python but can use Google. I'm pretty sure the `print` is right...

Comment: a more condensed and clean way to replace the last two lines is this: `print ''.join(item for item in result if isinstance(item, str))`

Comment: Dear downvoter - It's very possible there's an error here somewhere - I don't have Python here and didn't check the *whole* code, just a part on IDEONE, and gave reference to the rest. I don't mind the -2, but I'd appreciate a correction!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`re.subn()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.subn):

```
import re

s = 'AX(p>q)&E((-p)Ur)'
while True:
    s, n = re.subn(r'\([^)(]*\)', '', s)
    if n == 0:
        break
print(s)
```

#### Output

```
AX&E
```

Comment: Already suggested in my comment on one of @Kobi's answers over 2.5 hours earlier.

Comment: @John Machin: I know. I saw it after posting the answer. Initially I've encountered that code 4 years ago http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t398464-match-nested-parenthesis.html

Answer (score 0):

this is just how you do it:

```
# strings
# double and single quotes use in Python
"hey there! welcome to CIP"   
'hey there! welcome to CIP'  
"you'll understand python"          
'i said, "python is awesome!"'      
'i can\'t live without python'      
# use of 'r' before string
print(r"\new code", "\n")    

first = "code in"
last = "python"
first + last     #concatenation

# slicing of strings

user = "code in python!"

print(user)
print(user[5])   # print an element 
print(user[-3])  # print an element from rear end
print(user[2:6]) # slicing the string
print(user[:6])  
print(user[2:])
print(len(user))   # length of the string
print(user.upper()) # convert to uppercase
print(user.lstrip())
print(user.rstrip())
print(max(user)) # max alphabet from user string
print(min(user)) # min alphabet from user string
print(user.join([1,2,3,4]))

input()
```

Comment: some explanation with the code helps, otherwise it will be marked as low quality